# Can I use SAXON-CE in content script for extension use?

Tags: saxon, saxon-js

Has anyone tried to use SAXON-CE in extension content script?
So Xpath 2.0 can be used on DOM.

Comment: Firstly, Saxon-CE has been superseded by Saxon-JS, and this kind of thing is much more likely to workable with Saxon-JS. Secondly, I don't know the literal answer to the question ("Has anyone tried?"), but speaking for the team in Saxonica, it's not something we have tried; but I can't see any intrinsic reason why it shouldn't work, so give it a try and let us know.

Comment: What kind of extension is that question about? Browser extensions?

Comment: I was assuming https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts but it's not something I know much about

Comment: Yes, it is a browser extension, Saxon code will be executed as content script.

Comment: I will look into Saxon-JS